# Criação de thumbs dinâmicas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Como site como o Youtube, Netflix e muitos outros site fazem essa função? As thumbs são criadas no momento do mousemove / mouseenter na progress bar, ou elas já foram criadas antes e o player só exibe? Se são geradas no momento, como é feito?

[image: Thumbs dinâmicas Youtube]

Comment: Falando específicamente do youtube, não é possível fazer isso usando a API v3. Mais provável que elas sejam criadas no primeiro uso e guardadas pros seguintes. Tipo, quando vc passa o mouse e vem um preview em baixa-resolução depois troca pra um em resolução melhor. Como fazem eu não sei, mas se eu fosse inventar algo assim, provavelmente carregaria uma versão reduzida/comprimida do vídeo naquele frame e salvaria o jpg.

Comment: É a Xuxa no vídeo? kkkk

Comment: Sim, só abri o primeiro video que veio no youtube kk

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem em mãos a informação do tempo atual do vídeo ao mouse sobre a barra de progresso da duração do vídeo, você poderia enviar essa informação ao servidor com *Ajax* e utilizar o ffmpeg para poder capturar a thumb com o horário atual do vídeo.

Exemplo:

```
$video = 'path/to/video.flv';
$thumbnail = 'path/to/thumbnail.jpg';
$currentTime = isset($_POST['current_time']) ? $_POST['current_time'] : '00:00:01';
shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t {$currentTime} -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $thumbnail 2>&1")
```

Trecho de código retirado dessa resposta do SOEN: [How can I get a thumbnail from a video that a user has uploaded to my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240915/how-can-i-get-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-that-a-user-has-uploaded-to-my-server)

## Atualização

Existe uma biblioteca chamada [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) que facilita a manipulação de formatos de vídeo em PHP. Com ele também é possível extrair imagens de um determinado trecho.

Por exemplo:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(42));
$frame->save('image.jpg');
```

No exemplo acima, o  frame `42` do vídeo será capturado e salvo no formato  `jpg`. Sendo assim, você pode usar também esse recurso para fornecer uma imagem temporária do vídeo.

Comment: Mas se a pessoa sair deslizando o mouse por cima da barra de progresso, serão feitas diversas e solicitações ajax, isso não poder vir a sobrecarregar o servidor de alguma forma?

Comment: Não, mas aí você pode fazer um cache. Eu só dei uma visão geral, já que sua pergunta me pareceu mais "teorica". Na verdade, podem existir inúmeras maneiras de fazer isso.

Comment: Entendo, vou tentar instalar ffmpeg aqui pra testar, foi um pouco "teorica" mas esse é um recurso interessante para aprender já que não tem tutorial sobre

Comment: @LeoLetto eu não quis publicar aqui falando de algumas bibliotecas, porque eu nunca usei, mas tem algumas libraries que também ajuda nisso. Se eu achar alguma, te informo. (estou meio agarrado agora num site que estou fazendo).

Comment: Sem problemas, este é um recurso que eu gostaria de colocar num site que estou travadão também fazendo, mas ainda não entendo muito sobre ffmpeg